# Firebase comments not appearing on database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase. I'm using Swift. I want to store user's comments on my database however nothing seems to shows up on Firebase. Is something wrong with my code? 
Thanks for any help.

```
@IBAction func OnSubmitTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (textField.text != ""){

       let ref = Database.database().reference()
       let commentsReference = ref.child("comments")
       let newCommentID = commentsReference.childByAutoId().key
       let newCommentReference = commentsReference.child(newCommentID)
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return
        }
        let currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        newCommentReference.setValue(["uid": currentUserID, "commentText": textField.text!]) { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
               // ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }
```

Comment: First thing that pops out is that you're not doing anything with `error` right now. If you step through the code in a debugger, does `error` have a value? If so, does that value explain why nothing is written to the database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I debugged by putting breakpoints. Debugger can't get past the first return statement, which is the one under guard let currentUser = .... The thing is that in my app I'm not requesting for users to sign up or log in, they just directly post their comments. Shouldn't I need to use the Auth.auth() function? The reason is that in the later stages I don't want all the same comments appearing on different posts. I want to display users' comments based on a post selected by the user. I'm sorry for taking your time I'm new to Firebase.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a current user (something you'll probably want to add to your post by clicking the edit link under it). You might want to use an auth state listener to detect the user, as shown in the first sample under: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't want users to fill out a sign-up page or be logged in to their account to comment though. Is this still how I should be doing?

Comment: This isn't an answer but a suggestion; you are not using the key so it doesn't need to be obtained that way; just make it *let commentsRef = ref.child("comments").childByAutoId()* then *commentsRef.setValue...*. That just shortens it up a bit. @FrankvanPuffelen is spot on. Users should be authenticated to post comments, otherwise you wouldn't know who/where the comment came from. If you want users to be anonymous, then check out [Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth?authuser=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want users to be able to post comments. The users can optionally be signed in, in which case you want to also store their UID.

In incredibly simple way of doing this (I'm not a Swift expert either) is:

```
    var currentUserID = "anonymous"
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        currentUserID = currentUser.uid
    }
    newCommentReference.setValue(["uid": currentUserID, "commentText": textField.text!]) { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
    }
```

Now the `uid` property will either have the UID of the user who made the comment, or `"anonymous"` if there the user isn't signed in.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Fixed. Feel free to just edit next time I mess up. ;-)

Comment: I think you meant currentUserID = currentUser.uid instead of just currentUser. But either way, thank you very much it works now! Have a great day!!